# C# User Control (DLL) not showing in ASP.NET VB Web Application

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm in the process of converting a VS 2010 website project to a VS 2013 ASP.NET Web Application.

Most of process has gone smoothly thanks to the 'Convert to Web Application' option in the Projects menu.

Within the VB project there is a C# .ascx file and associated .ascx.cs file - a user control that is displayed on a menu item hover.  After some research I found that in a Web Application VB files and C# files can't be mixed as only VB or C# files can be compiled.

With this, I built a separate VS 2013 Web Application and built a DLL with the C# code.  I then added this DLL as a reference in the main VB Web Application and added the necessary ASP.NET code:

All compiles fine and the Web Application runs but the user control does not show.

1/ Is this actually possible?
2/ Am I missing something obvious?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the user control(DLL) shown in ToolBox view?

Comment: Anyway, this is actually possible.

Comment: With some further digging, the control is referenced but crashes with "System.NullReferenceException occurred in MyCtrls.dll, Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to access an element on the .ascx page in the DLL.

Comment: Are you setting project dependencies?